# remove class name in prototypejs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I need to convert following jquery into prototype.  How can I do it ?

```
$('.exercise-main .menu li').removeClass('current');

<div class="exercise-main">

<div class="menu">

    <ul id="myList">
            <li class="firstTab current" ></li>
            <li class="secondTab"></li>
            <li class="thirdTab"></li>

    </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$$(.exercise-main .menu li).invoke('removeClassName','current');
```